# R言語でデータを年代別にし、箱ひげ図を作成したい

Tags: r, rstudio, ggplot2

データは年齢と幸福度になります。
年代別の箱ひげ図をRで作成したいです。
私の想定としては、以下の二つが必要だと思っています。
・年齢を20～29などに設定し、まず年代別にする。
・箱ひげ図をそれぞれの年代でプロットするようにする。

```
#hensuu1 <- age, hensuu2 <- kouhukudo
ggplot(data, aes(x = hensuu1, y = hensuu2)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

上記コードを試しましたが、条件を定めていないため、上手くいきませんでした。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

下記のようなグラフが理想です。

[image: 理想のグラフ]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[base::cut()](https://search.r-project.org/R/refmans/base/html/cut.html) 関数を使って「年代」列を追加し，それを使って描画する記述例を示します。

なお，最後の `theme_bw()` の行は環境に合わせて変更または（前行の `+` も含めて）削除してください。

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(113)
data <- data.frame(年齢 = sample(20:59, 100, replace=TRUE),
                   幸福度 = rnorm(100, mean=3.0, sd=0.6))

data$年代 <- cut(data$年齢, breaks = c(20, 30, 40, 50, 60),
                 labels = c("20代", "30代", "40代", "50代"),
                 right=FALSE)

ggplot(data, aes(x=年代, y=幸福度)) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    coord_cartesian(ylim=c(1, 5)) +
    labs(x="年代", y="幸福度") +
    theme_bw(base_family="HiraginoSans-W3", base_size=14)
```

[image: 描画結果]

Answer (score 0):

承認済の回答を参考にし、望み通りの動きになりました。

```
# ライブラリ
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# データから必要な列を抜き出し、データフレームを作成
data <- data.frame(年齢 = , #元データの年齢の列に指定
                   幸福度 = #元データの幸福度の列に指定
                   )

# 年齢を年代別にし、”年代”の列を追加
data <- data %>%
  mutate(年代 = cut(data$年齢, breaks = c(0, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, Inf),
                  labels = c("10代", "20代", "30代", "40代", "50代", 
                             "60代", "70代", "80代", "90代"),
                  right = FALSE))

# 箱ひげ図作成
ggplot(data, aes(x = 年代, y = 幸福度)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  labs(title = "年齢別の幸福度箱ひげ図", x = "年代", y = "幸福度")
```